# Sending only one file through lftp

Tags: lftp

I am trying to create a command line to send files to my server. 
Everything is working great to send a folder,
but it fails for a single file. 
The command I am running is

```
lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow off; mirror --reverse --verbose --delete -i .htaccess ./ /my-folder/; bye" -u user:password host.com
```

But the command is sending everything and not only `.htaccess` file,
and I do not understand why. 
What is happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extraneaous `./` in your `mirror` command.

```
mirror --reverse --verbose --delete -i .htaccess ./ /my-folder/
                                                 ^
                                                HERE
```

Comment: Thanks, `./` is the local folder. If I am running `mirror --reverse --verbose --delete -i .htaccess  /my-folder/` I have an error telling me `mirror: Access failed:  /my-folder/: No such file or directory` `mirror ` is trying to find `.htaccess` on the local and not the remote server

Comment: @Ajouve I don't know lftp, but it seems to me it is doing exactly what you told it to do with `--reverse`. Beware, there is also a `-i` option that may mislead you. I'm under the impression you don't understand the command you are executing. You should be cautious and take a look at the [man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) because there is a `--delete` option here that may cause havocs if you don't double-check your command.

Comment: Ok, thanks I tried without delete but I have the same issue

Comment: @xhienne im really curious that if you don't know lftp then why you are doing ninja answers???